# What's a Dual Basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, modules

If $L/K$ is a finite extension of fields with $v_1, ... , v_n$ a basis, then we have an isomorphism of $K$-modules $L/K \rightarrow Hom_K(L,K)$, where a basis for $Hom_K(L,K)$ is the "dual basis" of $v_1, ... , v_n$: $K$-module homomorphisms $v_1^{\ast}, ... , v_n^{\ast}$ defined by $v_i^{\ast}(v_j) = \delta_{ij}$.

But for a bilinear form $B: L \times L \rightarrow K$, for example the trace map $Tr_{L/K}$, I have also seen authors talking about another "dual basis" $w_1, ... , w_n$, by which they mean a basis for $L/K$ for which $B(v_i,w_j) = \delta_{ij}$.

What is the connection between these two different notions of dual basis?  And how does one prove the existence of the second kind of dual basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unified view comes from considering two vector spaces $V, W$ of the same finite dimension over the field $K$, and a bilinear form form $B : V \times W \to K$ which is non-degenerate (in both variables).

Here two bases $v_{i}$ of $V$ and $w_{i}$ of $W$ are dual (with respect to $B$) if $B(v_{i}, w_{j}) = \delta_{ij}$.

An example is given by $W = V^{\star}$, and $B(v, f) = f(v)$. This is quite general, because the map $W \to V^{\star}$ given by $w \mapsto (v \mapsto B(v, w))$ yields an isomorphism between $W$ and $V^{\star}$.

Here I am writing $V^{\star} = \hom_{K}(V, K)$.

See [dual pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_pair).

Answer (score 0):

Every bilinear form on $V$ gives rise to a "transpose" operation from $V$ to $V^*$. If $V$ is finite-dimensional, the transpose is invertible, giving a map $V^* \to V$. This allows one to, to some extent, treat dual vectors as if they were ordinary vectors, in much the same way that one often conflates $n\times 1$ "column vectors" with $1 \times n$ "row vectors".

Specifically, the map $V \to V^*$ is the function $v \mapsto B(v, -)$. The notation $B(v,-)$ means the the function that takes a vector $w$ and sends it to $B(v,w)$, and so $B(v,-)$ is a dual vector.

More generally, any bilinear map $U \times V \to W$ corresponds to a linear map $U \to \hom(V, W)$ in the same way.